# How to create sticky headers on scroll with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-sticky

So I have tables that I am trying to classify by date, with headers like (today, yesterday, last week, ...) and I am trying to make them sticky depending on the current table in the viewport. I tried using the `react-sticky` library specifically `the stacked example` as it seems to be the effect I am looking for but I am unable to recreate it.

Please, am I missing some thing on the library usage.

**Also a solution without the library is very welcome**

What I have been trying

```
export default function CustomizedTables() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <StickyContainer>
      <Sticky topOffset={20}>
        {(props) => (
          <div className={reduceCSS.tableHistoryTitle_day}>Today</div>
        )}
      </Sticky>
      <TableContainer component={Paper} elevation={0}>
        <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="customized table">
          <TableBody>
            {rows.map((row) => (
              <StyledTableRow key={row.name} elevation={0}>
                <StyledTableCell align="left" className={classes.iconCell}>
                  <AssignmentReturnedSharpIcon className={classes.inputIcon} />
                </StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell align="left">{row.calories}</StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">
                  {row.name}
                </StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.fat}</StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.protein}</StyledTableCell>
              </StyledTableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </StickyContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can just use `position: sticky` and `top: 0` in your `th`. Here's an example:
https://codepen.io/ipetriniith/pen/JjGeOKQ

Comment: Aight, let me play around with it and see if I can recreate those sticky list headers that that library offers. Feel free to share more if you know how to :)

Answer (score 17):

Follow the steps outlined below, for a sticky header on ***ReactJs***,

Header.js

```
const Header = () => {
    
        // Sticky Menu Area
        useEffect(() => {
            window.addEventListener('scroll', isSticky);
            return () => {
                window.removeEventListener('scroll', isSticky);
            };
        });
    
               
        /* Method that will fix header after a specific scrollable */
               const isSticky = (e) => {
                    const header = document.querySelector('.header-section');
                    const scrollTop = window.scrollY;
                    scrollTop >= 250 ? header.classList.add('is-sticky') : header.classList.remove('is-sticky');
                };
            return (
        <>
         <header className="header-section d-none d-xl-block">
              ..add header code
         </header>
        </>
      );   
   }
```

Header.css - Custom Style (for your header)

```
.is-sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 24px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 15%);
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
    animation: 500ms ease-in-out 0s normal none 1 running fadeInDown;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

---

> ### Note!
>
> Already compiled via link:
> https://codesandbox.io/s/sticky-header-dyews?file=/src/App.js

Comment: This code is a react anti-pattern for two reasons: 1. this `useEffect` will add a scroll listener *every time the component re-renders*. (you can add ` console.log` to the callback to see it fire) 2. you shouldn't manipulate the DOM - `classList.add` inside react. The proper structure is to set state inside the scroll callback.

Comment: this is just a nightmare for such a simple requirement

Comment: @awongh how should this be solved using react correctly? And I am stressing the "React" or at least "JS" part because not every sticky header can be solved with 'position:sticky'. Any suggested pattern?

Comment: @LukášŘádek I gave an answer above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72618981/271932

Comment: thanks! can we follow up there? 

Comment: Adding a useCallback to an abstracted fn called by the listener will fix the rerender issue. However, in React 20 this won't matter.

Answer (score 7):

after reading lots of js code that accomplishes this, I achieved this like so...

```
.header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In react you need to set the class by calling a `useState` function.

You can set the listener for this in a `useEffect` that runs once on component render.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Header = () => {
  const [sticky, setSticky] = useState("");

  // on render, set listener
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("hello");
    window.addEventListener("scroll", isSticky);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", isSticky);
    };
  }, []);

  const isSticky = () => {
    /* Method that will fix header after a specific scrollable */
    const scrollTop = window.scrollY;
    const stickyClass = scrollTop >= 250 ? "is-sticky" : "";
    setSticky(stickyClass);
    console.log(stickyClass);
  };

  const classes = `header-section d-none d-xl-block ${sticky}`;

  return (
    <>
      <header className={classes}>..add header code</header>
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/sticky-header-forked-ybo6j9

Most of this code referenced from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69944800/271932 (which has correct CSS but not react code)

Comment: How would you maintain the original offset of the sticky element, instead of hardcoding the 250 value?

Comment: @JasonBert if i understand your question, the 250 can be changed to the height of the sticky element. (the example element doesn't have a CSS height set, but you can set one in the CSS) then change the 250 to match that height.

Comment: I am using this approach to make a header sticky but not just by changing css `position` but by actually updating the `top` property. I have tried it both ways - setting the style directly using DOM manipulation and by setting it as a state, both of which are lagging unfortunatelly, while I have been using this approach in vanilla JS/jQuery for a long time with success. Anz suggestion how to approach this when there is a need to set property very frequently while keeping the performance?

Comment: *> not just by changing css position but by actually updating the top property*

Not sure what you mean, because `top` *is* a CSS position property. It's not a property of the HTML element. If you wanted, for example, to change the `top` property every time the scroll event listener fired, it doesn't seem like the performance is that bad.... although it could depend on exactly what is being updated: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sticky-header-forked-8ly9j9

Comment: @awongh I mean that I am not just chaning the `position` from `relative` to `sticky` on some threshold but actually keeping the element in place by continually updating the `top` property. The performance is not terrible, but you can definitely see it is lagging behind. I have looked at your example and I have tried it similarly, but I will give it a try to separate the logic just for the sticky component etc. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`position: sticky`  is realy cool.

[Its compatibility is also ok](https://caniuse.com/?search=position%3A%20sticky)

Just pay some attention to the parent element's height, and most of time, you may need to cooperate it with `React.Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

```
position: fixed
```

works in my case . add it to the class navbar

```
.main-nav{
position: fixed;
```

}
html/jsx file

```
<nav className='main-nav'>...</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to make the header `position: fixed` and I had to set the height of the header-container.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header-container {
  height: 81px
}

.header {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 81px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container">
  <div class="header">
    header
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).


Where does it come from?
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.

Where can I get some?
There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
</div>
```

`position: sticky` didn't work because the header is inside a div with other header elements.